# Literature similar to Minsky's "Steps Toward Artificial Intelligence" (1961)?

Tags: reference-request, artificial-intelligence, history

With great pleasure I was just reviewing Marvin Minsky's publication *"Steps Toward Artificial Intelligence"* from 1961.

Now I would like to know whether there are any more compilations about the approaches to artificial intelligence with a similar depth and scope by authors with similar credibility, dating before or after the above mentioned work.

Is there any other notable publication that follows up on this (besides obviously Russel & Norvig's *AIMA*)?

Or maybe something presenting the problem from a different angle (e.g., from the *"bottom up"*-side of things, Deep Learning maybe)?

I'm interested in sources that attempt to outline or help understand the big picture of research in artificial intelligence. Not so much about the actual progress in specific disciplines.

Comment: So, you want a historical overview of developments in _any_ subfield of artificial intelligence? Or do you want a 'continuation' that (possibly) references the parts with Minsky's publication stops?

Comment: @Discretelizard The latter! I'm interested in sources that attempt to outline or help understand the big picture of research in artificial intelligence. Not so much about the actual progress in specific disciplines.